# Syntax of select_hour and select_minute helpers

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to save opening and closing times of venues for every day of the week.

I am new to Rails and Ruby and have gone a complex route :

I request the hours and minutes in the New view and then convert it to seconds in the Create controller function before saving it.

Though I am running an issue when trying to create the Edit and Update controller. This is mainly due to the formatting of the select_hour and select_minute helpers.

(As my model saves the times as seconds from midnight I have defined attr_accessor for each hour and minute field that I calculate in the New function of the controller)

Here is the code in my New view:

```
<%= select_hour(0,{}, name: 'mondayopeninghour') %>
```

my attr_accessor is the same name as the field which is 'mondayopeninghour' but I don't know how to replace the original 0 (default value) from the New view by the  'mondayopeninhour' value from the Edit view..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting up some instance variables @monday_opening_hour in your controller, then accessing that

```
 <%= select_hour(@monday_opening_hour, {}, name: :monday_opening_hour) %>
```

I have taken the liberty of updating your names to more conventional ruby style BTW.  No extra charge.

Comment: Many thanks Mitch. I will try this. Though I have tried <%= select_hour(mondayopeninghour,{}, name: 'mondayopeninghour') %> which I think should work as I have allowed this value through attr_accessor, and derived it from the seconds value with an easy calculation involving floor and modulo (for the minutes) : @mymodel.mondayopeninghour = ... Should'nt it belong like a normal value of the model treated as such in the form ?

Comment: (this is purely to understand how Rails works, as I do think I will create a new instance variable for each field in the form as you recommend it)

Comment: You could store the data in 2 ways: as a series of separate fields (like you are) or as an array in a serialized attribute.  The second is easier, but will not allow easy queries if you need to do that.  If you want to keep separate fields, you can still create a method like `opening_hours` that builds the array from the separate fields.  Just depends on what you need to do with the data.